# Minecraft command block messages in chat in Spanish

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In my minecraft server/realm I have done this command block that allows one person to sleep and I did the command and that command block disappeared. Now every time a person sleeps a chat message comes up in Spanish:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried the command `/gamerule commandblockoutput false` but it didn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: "a chat thing comes up in Spanish" Can you be a little more descriptive, such as including screenshots? Also be aware that gamerules are case-sensitive and would need to be `commandBlockOutput`, provided that's even related to the issue.

Comment: well yes i have before tired it commandBlockOutput and that hasn't worked and ill add pictures one sec

Comment: ive changed it to english twice trying to overwrite it but it still stays

Comment: That's the result of a `/tellraw` command. You have one that's written out like that being activated.

Comment: The actual question being asked here appears to be how to disable the unwanted command block, which is answered by the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't already know, command blocks are case-sensitive. Make sure to double-check and make sure no typos have been made.